# Cannot center inner div with text-align: center

Tags: html, css

I had previously thought that both of the code blocks below would correctly center a div (with some issues with older browsers of course). The first method uses `text-align: center` whereas the second method uses left and right margins of `auto`. However, the first block of code below does not center the inner div as I was expecting. Any ideas why?

```html
<div style="text-align: center; background-color: red;">
    <div style="border: solid 1px black; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue">Not working</div>
</div>
```

The following code does center the div:

```html
<div style="background-color: red;">
  <div style="border: solid 1px black; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">Works</div>
</div>
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aaaL9try/1/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. I already knew how to center a div as specified in the second example I posted. I was wondering why the first example did not work. Pete gave the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a block-level element, its position won't be effected by the text-align property. If you set it to **display-inline**, it will work.

```
<div style="text-align: center; background-color: red;">
    <div style="border: solid 1px black; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue; display: inline-block;">It will work now</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great. Thanks! I did not know that text-align only applied to inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

The div that is centered has `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto`, the div that doesn't work lacks any margins.

See this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/kf7mm8gc/)

On the top box, I added: `margin: 0 auto` which is shorthand for: `margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

Comment: Yes, I typed the code myself so already knew that the first example did not have margins set to auto. I was wondering why text-align did not work as was answered by Pete above.